# C# WPF SQL connection error in one project and not another

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

This baffles me. I am trying to run a few lines of code to connect to our SQL Server database, as I have done plenty of times before. In this project, it just fails. If I spin up a new barebones WPF (.net 4.8) project, the following code works flawlessly.

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = SRVSQL03; Initial Catalog = PRODDATA; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = XXX; Password = XXX; TrustServerCertificate = True");
cn.Open();

var cmd = new SqlCommand("select top (1) name from Employee where active = 1 and EmployeeCode = @id", cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(Input));

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
while (dr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(dr[0]);
}
```

It times out on cn.Open():

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
> Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

[System.Data version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2VSP.png)

Cleaning / Rebuilding the solution gets me nowhere. I am thinking maybe a reference may cause trouble or some broken pieces somewhere. Tried to delete and rebuild the obj folder too.

Thanks in advance

[Reference list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nroWB.png)

Comment: The issue is with the connection string.  Best way of debugging is to use SQL Server Management Studio which give better error messages than c#.  It appears the instance of the serve is wrong or the credentials are wrong.  check the Data Source and see if it works with SSMS.  Set the credentials to SQL Server if you are using Username and Password or Windows credentials if you are using Integrated Security = true.

Comment: The connection string works fine. Obviously changed the UN/PW. Tried the same string in the dummy solution I created. Even tried other strings that also should work. Works fine in the parallel project. I would say that rules out the various firewall/SQL server setup issues that could have been, and reduces it to ... conflicting / broken parts in my solution itself, no?

Comment: Are you running between same two machines and working?   Does code  work when running executable outside VS?  If you are an admin VS does automatically run with AS ADMIN.  You have to right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  I suspect when you are running a different app you are not running inside VS.  When you are failing you are inside VS.

Comment: Two instances of VS on the same machine running up against our server that hosts the SQL DB. One works, the other doesn't. My lead atm. is that including the WinRT api - for a pdf viewer - is breaking it. Somehow. At least I get the same error if I break the solution down to just that subproject, and try to inject my SQL from there.

Comment: Perhaps you have some kind of proxy setting somewhere? By the way, you should dispose your SQL objects with `using` blocks

Answer (score 0):

Took awhile to figure out, but apparently running the code from a networkdrive (VPN) caused the issue. Might have hit an internal firewall somewhere.

The same code running directly from my machine worked fine.